# Как ускорить бинарный поиск на частично неотсортированном массиве

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Решаю задачку, суть в том, чтобы вернуть индекс элемента, если такого нет, то вернуть -1
Массив представляет собой сдвиг отсортированных элементов, например:

```
1. [10, 11, 12, 13, 7, 8, 9]
2. [30, 31, 32, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
3. [50, 56, 72, 98, 10, 26, 35, 41, 49] и так далее
```

Я решаю с помощью бинарного поиска. Суть в том, что я проверяю, есть ли элемент справа или слева. Если он справа, делю правую часть, если он слева - делю левую. И так пока не дойду до искомого элемента. Но тесты не проходят по времени. Подскажите как можно ускорить решение

```
def binary_search_by_index(nums, x) -> int:
    if x not in nums:
        return - 1

    low, high = 0, len(nums) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if x == nums[mid]:
            return mid
        elif x == nums[low]:
            return low
        elif x == nums[high]:
            return high
        elif x in nums[:mid]:
            high = mid - 1
        elif x in nums[mid:]:
            low = mid + 1


target = int(input())  # 5
array = list(map(int, input().split()))  # [4, 5, 6, 2, 3]
print(binary_search_by_index(array, target))  # -> 1
```

Comment: Вообразите что элементы собраны в кольцо. выберите из кольца три элемента на равном расстоянии по кругу. Между самым маленьким элементом и предыдущим есть место "стыка". Отрезок со "стыком" разбейте пополам и выберите половину со "стыком". Через логарифм делений вы найдёте "стык". Теперь можно делать обычный двоичный поиск.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy если не затруднит, можете написать подробнее про часть со стыком - не очень понимаю принцип

Comment: Конечно не пройдут по времени, ведь у вас не двоичный поиск, а линейный

Comment: @tym32167 да это я уже понял - из головы вылетело, что in за О(n) работает + еще срезы. Не лучшее решение, мягко говоря

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фишка в том, чтобы сравнивать средний элемент с краями диапазона. Если порядок не нарушен, то соответствующая половина не изломана, и при вхождении искомого элемента в диапазон ищем в данной половине.

```
def BSinBroken (arr, value):
    lo = 0
    hi = len(arr)-1
    while lo <= hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if arr[mid] == value:
            return mid

        if arr[lo] <= arr[mid]: #сортирован левый
            if arr[lo] <= value <= arr[mid]:
                hi = mid - 1   #ищем в нём
            else:
                lo = mid + 1   #ищем в правом
        else:
                if arr[mid] <= value <= arr[hi]:
                    lo = mid + 1
                else:
                    hi = mid - 1
    return -1
```